# What does this error mean? "Error: No valid exports main found"

Tags: gulp

I'm setting up a new Gulp project.

Basically I've just copied over my gulpfile.js config from a previous project and reinstalled the npm modules locally.

When I run 'gulp' I get this error:

> Error: No valid exports main found for
> '/var/www/mysite.localdev/wp-content/themes/aotearoasupport/node_modules/copy-props/node_modules/is-plain-object'

What does this error actually mean?
How can I use it to debug my gulp config?

Comment: were you able to fix this? I'm having the same problem.